# Flutter how to draw a curved path between widgets keeping it responsive

Tags: flutter, web, drawing, responsive

I want to make a curved path between widgets on my website, like a story timeline.
I have managed to draw the curved paths, however, the problem arises when resizing the page as they move and start overlapping with the widgets.

[What I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5409.png)

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOPTK.png)

[The issue when resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0VdM.png)

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sales_pitch/views/1.dart';
import 'package:sales_pitch/views/2.dart';
import 'package:sales_pitch/views/4.dart';
import 'package:sales_pitch/views/5.dart';
import 'package:sales_pitch/views/6.dart';
import 'package:sales_pitch/views/landing.dart';
import 'package:sales_pitch/widgets/curved_painter.dart';

import '../constants/assets.dart';
import '3.dart';

class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeView({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeView> createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    List<Widget> sections = [
      const LandingView(),
      const FirstView(),
      const SecondView(),
      const ThirdView(),
      const FourthView(),
      const FifthView(),
      const SixthView(),
      const SizedBox(height: 250),
    ];

    //* I have also tried using positioned images however these also moved and screwed up the layout
    List<Widget> lines = [
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 0.95,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: size.width * 0.18,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(1),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 1.42,
        left: size.width * 0.2,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: size.width * 0.3,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(2),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 1.58,
        right: size.width * 0.2,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: size.width * 0.35,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(3),
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 1.75,
        left: size.width * 0.15,
        right: size.width * 0.1,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: size.height * 0.2,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(4),
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 2.5,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: size.height * 0.26,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(5),
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 3.2,
        left: size.width * 0.4,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: size.height * 0.3,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(6),
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 4,
        right: size.width * 0.1,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: size.height * 0.45,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(7),
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: size.height * 5.4,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: size.height * 0.2,
            child: Image.asset(
              AppAssets.getAppPath(8),
              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: size.height * (sections.length / 2)),
            //...lines,
            //TODO: add the new lines to a list to cleanup code
            //* First Line
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * 0.95,
              left: size.width * 0.35,
              height: size.height * 0.23,
              width: size.width * 0.15,
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: CurvePainter(),
                willChange: true,
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
            //* Second Line
            Positioned(
              top: size.height * 1.35,
              left: size.width * 0.15,
              height: size.height * 0.12,
              width: size.width * 0.35,
              child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.rotationY(pi),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: CurvePainter(),
                  willChange: true,
                  child: Container(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: sections),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have also tried using images exported from Figma and positioning them as needed, however, the same issue arises. I would also prefer the lines in code so they can easily be changed in the future.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK

1. Second line with text at the right can be done with `Row` widget.
2. Third line -> same
3. Fouth line -> `Column` + `Row` below line with text and lorem block.

It's easier to do it with rows, rather than calculate it with positioned. Is see overlapping only at 1st line, but it can also be done with `Row\Column`

Comment: You’re right about those ones yes, the problem is when the line goes over the end of one section and the start of the other, like the first line for example.

Comment: I was thinking I could just do a row/column solution and draw each part of the line separately at the split, but that seems like a lot more work